# Label not refreshing with the correct date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I have a label and two arrow buttons. When I push on the left arrow I want to show one day less than that date at the moment. And when I push on the right arrow a day should be added.

At the moment this is my code.

```
- (IBAction)addDay:(id)sender {
    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = 1;
    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSString *dateNow = _lblDate.text;

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE. d MMMM YYYY"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateNow];

    date = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:date options:0];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    _lblDate.text = dateString;

}

- (IBAction)deleteDay:(id)sender {

    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = 1;
    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSString *dateNow = _lblDate.text;

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE. d MMMM YYYY"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateNow];

    date = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:date options:0];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    _lblDate.text = dateString;

}
```

But for some reason or another the dates are wrong. There is no pattern when I'm adding and deleting dates.

Can anybody help me ?

Kind regards

Comment: did you tried NSLogging for check the correct value of date formed?

Comment: How, exactly, are the dates wrong?

Comment: Go modular approach use this code -(NSString*)shortHandDate {
 if (shortHandDateFormatter == nil) {
  shortHandDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [shortHandDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE d MMMM yyyy"];
 }

 return [shortHandDateFormatter stringFromDate:self];

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for addition is correct. However relying on string to date conversion is creating problems. I'll advise you to take a `NSDate` object as instance variable and then update this instance variable on going to next or previous day. After updating value you can use dateformatter to retrieve string from this date. Right now when you use your label's text to generate date, it creates problems.
So that's how you can do it

```
// currentDate is my instance variable.
currentDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE. d MMMM YYYY"];
dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

And that's how your nextdayfunctionwill look Like

```
   (IBAction)nextDay:(id)sender {

       NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
       dayComponent.day = 1;
       NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

       NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
       [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE. d MMMM YYYY"];

       currentDate = [[theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:currentDate options:0] retain];
       NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
       dateLabel.text = dateString;
    }
```

And here is previous day

```
enter code here

    (IBAction)previousDay:(id)sender {

        NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        dayComponent.day = -1;
        NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE. d MMMM YYYY"];

        currentDate = [[theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:currentDate options:0] retain];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
        dateLabel.text = dateString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the main issue, but in `- (IBAction)deleteDay:(id)sender`, `dayComponent.day = 1;` should be `dayComponent.day = -1;`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with this.

1. Not actually decrementing the day by one (looks like addition?)
2. Not updating the UI on the main thread.

Try making these changes:

```
- (IBAction)deleteDay:(id)sender {

    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = -1;
    /* snip */
}
```

And...

`[_lblDate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:dateString waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: what leads you to issue #2? These methods are called when buttons are tapped. That will be on the main thread.

Comment: A CYA move, just in case the methods may be called from another thread (I've done this in the past).  The OP also hasn't specified how the dates are wrong, so I'm listing everything I can think of to help.

Answer (score 0):

To add a day you need to addTimeInterval of one day as follows

```
NSDate *newDate1 = [date addTimeInterval:60*60*24];
```

To subtract a day do following

```
NSDate *newDate2 = [date addTimeInterval:-60*60*24];
```